# Grant user rights to access certain tabs of a plugin

Tags: permissions

I found out a way to grant a user permission to access a single plugin but it has its flaws. Right now there are 6 tabs on the options page of this plugin.

[image: The tabs]

The user has access to all these tabs now. I just want him to be able to access "1, 2 and 4 ". The rest should **not** be visible for him.

This is the piece of code I have set up for this. It allows the Editor to access the settings page. See image for the settings page.

```
if ( is_admin() )  
{  
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_plugin_for_editors' );  
}  

function add_plugin_for_editors()   
{  
    if (!current_user_can( 'manage_options' ))  
    {  
        add_menu_page('Rooster', 'Rooster', 'editor', 'rooster', 'rooster_html_page');  
    }  
}
```

If something is unclear please let me know. Feel free to edit my post if you see any grammatical errors.

Comment: What's the logic for access to these tabs? Do you have permissions for each tab and roles set up with sets of those permissions, or will it be a per-user property? You could possibly hide that in user-meta and not expose it for editing by the users but that feels conceptually wrong as a user generally owns their own meta.

Comment: The permission is set for a whole user-group ( all the tabs in one go ). How would i go about hiding the tabs?

Comment: This tutorial helped me before to solve a similar issue http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2013/02/wordpress-admin-body-class.html. It tells you how to modify the admin classes, add new classes, and target them with css for the admin interface. So, the goal is to add a class that's unique to that user or role to the body tag, so that if that class is present you can hide elements using it.

Comment: Can you please post the complete code you're using to setup the tabs?